# simple_forms custom data attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I would like to have an additional data attribute on an input tag generated by simple_form.
The following does not work:

```
<%= f.input :date, :as => 'date_picker', :data => {:datepicker => :datepicker}  %>
```

How could this be done? Is it possible at all? As you might have guessed: I am trying to add bootstrap-datepicker to my site without using explicit js to initialize the date picker.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The correct API is:

```
f.input :date, :as => 'date_picker', :input_html => { :data => {:datepicker => :datepicker} }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me somehow… simple_form 2.1 / rails 3.0.20 / ruby 1.9.3p484 / haml 4.0.4

Comment: Is there an update for this with more recent versions of simple_form?

Comment: @sixty4bit I'm wondering what error you get?

Did you try with `f.input :date, :as => :string, :input_html => {...}` ? (also don't forget the last '  } ' as it is slightly hidden..)

Comment: `= f.input :due_date, as: :string, :input_html => { :data => {:provide => :datepicker} }` this works for me. I am using bootstrap with https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 10):

For prosperity. On Rails 4.2.5 and Simple Form 3.2.1

The above from @rafaelfranca works for inputs:

```
f.input :first_name, input_html: { data: { cool_stuff: "yes" } }
```

If you want to add a data attribute to the simple_form_for helper:

```
simple_form_for @form, html: { data: { super_cool_key: "secret" } } do |f|
```

Note the difference: `input_html:` vs `html:`
Also, the underscores will automatically get changed to a dash.